# Multiple Aggregrate Functions on Same Field With Different Criteria in SQL

Tags: sql, db2, aggregate-functions

I have 2 tables. The first one is `MYTABLE.MAR` and the second one is `MYTABLE.MHR`. `MAR` has columns `DOCNO` and `DT_CLOSED`,  `MHR` has columns `DOCNO`, `STA_CD`, `STA_DT`.

The column `DOCNO` in `MHR` can have multiple data in `STA_CD`. For each `DOCNO`, I need to get the `MIN(STA_DT) where STA_CD = 'P2'` and the `MAX(STA_DT) where STA_CD = 'C3'`. I can get correct info for one of the STA_CD criteria with the following code:

```
SELECT
    A.DOCNO, A.DT_CLOSED, B.STA_DT AS PICK_DATE
FROM 
    MYTABLE.MAR A 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    MYTABLE.MHR B ON B.DOCNO = A.DOCNO
WHERE 
    B.STA_DT = (SELECT MIN(B.STA_DT) 
                FROM MYTABLE.MHR B
                WHERE B.DOCNO = A.DOCNO AND B.STA_CD = 'P2')
    AND A.DT_CLOSED = '2018041'
GROUP BY 
    A.DOCNO, A.DT_CLOSED, B.STA_DT
```

Sample data:

```
  DOCNO      DT_CLOSED         STA_CD     PICK_DT        PACK_DT
  ---------------------------------------------------------------
   ABCD      2018041             P2        2/12/18
   ABCD      2018041             C35                   2/13/18
   ABCD      2018041             P2        2/13/18
   ABCD      2018041             C35                   2/14/18
```

Expected results to get the Min Pick_date(STA_DT where STA_CD ='P2') and the Max Pack_Date (STA_DT where STA_CD = 'C35') for DocNo

```
DOCNO   DT_CLOSED     PICK_DATE   PACK_DATE
-------------------------------------------
ABCD    2018041        2/12/18     2/14/18
```

I have tried Select Join subqueries and searched many similar topic here but can't get this to produce desired results.  Any help would be appreciated.  This is my first question and I'm a novice at SQL so be gentle.  Thanks.

Comment: Which dbms?????

Comment: I use SQL thru QMF.

Comment: `SQL` is just a language used by many dbms vendor.  It still doesn't answer the question which dbms you use.

Comment: IBM DB2 Query Management Facility (QMF).   Is this not the answer you are looking for?

Comment: Now you answer my question.  If you had put `db2` tag with your question, we wouldn't have needed this back and forth comment.

Comment: As I said, I'm a novice and this is my first question.  I'm sorry and will remember to do this in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create to auxiliary tables that contain your min and max values, respectively, and then join them onto your `mar` table by `docno`, like so:

```
select
  mar.docno,
  mar.dt_closed
  t_min.min_sta_dt,
  t_max.max_sta_dt
from mar
left outer join 
    (select docno, min(sta_dt) as min_sta_dt
     from mhr 
     where sta_cd = 'P2'
     group by docno) t_min on mar.docno = t_min.docno
left outer join
    (select docno, max(sta_dt) as max_sta_dt
     from mhr
     where sta_dt = 'C3'
     group by docno) t_max on mar.docno = t_max.docno
```

I'm jusing standard SQL, but have no access to a DB2 instance, so I hope it'll work for you out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    A.DOCNO, A.DT_CLOSED, MIN (CASE WHEN B.STA_CD ='P2' THEN B.STA_DT ELSE null END) , MAX (CASE WHEN B.STA_CD ='C35' THEN B.STA_DT ELSE null END) 
FROM 
MYTABLE.MAR A 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
         MYTABLE.MHR B ON B.DOCNO = A.DOCNO

GROUP BY 
A.DOCNO, A.DT_CLOSED
```

I'm using TSQL but should be similar for the others

Comment: I use SQL thru QMF.  I tried this and only received NULL in both fields.  Thank you.